# Understanding naming of imports and packages

Tags: python, package

`from sklearn import linear_model`

For the code above, I understand that "sklearn" is a package so what exactly is "liner_model"?

Comment: In this case, It's right in the URL: scikit-learn.org/stable/ _modules_ /linear_model.html linear_model is a module in the sklearn package or library. And in the first section on that page, "Across the _module_, we..."

Comment: And generically, in a from import the name (`sklearn`) can be a simple python module too. The name you import with `from`does not require a qualifier prefix to use, and it is not linked to the module it came from. You get your own copy. As opposed to this with the `import` form names are linked but require qualification to use (`somemodule.somename`).

Answer (score 2):

It can really be anything, a module-level variable (ie string, integer), a class, a function or a sub-module . Some examples:

```
from pandas import match
from pandas import json
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import __version__

print(match)
print(json)
print(DataFrame)
```

outputs

```
<function match at 0x0000016BE3082950>  # function
<module 'pandas.json' from '\lib\site-packages\pandas\json.py'>  # module
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>  # class
0.23.4  # string
```

In that particualr case, `sklearn.linear_model` is a module, according to its [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.linear_model):

> The sklearn.linear_model module ...